# Catch ObjectContent serialization errors in DelegatingHandler without reading response

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have built a request logging `DelegatingHandler` using the details in [this blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/pglavich/archive/2012/02/26/asp-net-web-api-request-response-usage-logging.aspx).

I do not want to read the request or response bodies (doubling-up this work seems silly on a potentially high-volume web service); all I want to do is assign each request a unique ID, log the URI and headers; write the request ID to the response in another header and then log the response (Success/fail) and any exception that occurred.

```
protected override System.Threading.Tasks.Task<HttpResponseMessage> 
  SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, 
  System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  DateTime receivedUTC = DateTime.UtcNow;

  //I use the Request properties to persist a Request's ID
  var requestID = request.GetRequestUID();
  if (requestID == null)
    requestID = request.SetRequestUID();

  //grab the base response task
  var baseResult = base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

  return baseResult.ContinueWith(innerTask =>
  {
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<HttpResponseMessage>();

    //note I've got rid of SynchronizationContext code out of this
    //to keep it shorter

    //construct the log packet
    LogData toLog = new LogData()
        {
          ReceivedUTC = receivedUTC,
          Request = request,
          RequestID = requestID,
        };

    //get the response
    try
    {
      tcs.SetResult(innerTask.Result);
      //NOTE - If this request actually fails response serialization,
      //       Then the above result will actually look fine, because
      //       The error hasn't occurred yet!
      toLog.Response = innerTask.Result;
      //this adds a header
      AddRequestIDToResponse(toLog.Response, requestID);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      tcs.TrySetException(ex);
      toLog.Ex = ex;
    }

    //fire the logging call asynchronously (code elided, just some DB work)
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Log(toLog));
    return tcs.Task;
  }).Unwrap();
}
```

This all works absolutely fine for nearly all requests, except when an exception occurs whilst the `ObjectContent` returned from an action method gets serialized to the response.

If this happens, the above code has already fired, and the response message it sees in the try/catch block above appears as a normal `200` with the `ObjectContent` containing the object that will eventually fail serialization.  That does makes sense - since serialization to the response body hasn't occurred yet.

How do I change this code (without forcing a read on the `ObjectContent`) to ensure that the response message I see is the ***actual*** message that the client receives, after content formatting has taken place?  Should I be looking at a different extensibility point?

Comment: Could this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16552715/how-do-i-trap-a-serializationexception-in-web-api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a tentative answer until someobody (hopefully) comes along and proves me wrong; it would appear that this is going to be nigh on impossible within the Web API pipeline itself without copying and pasting a huge amount of code.

The content serialization is triggered at the very top of the Web API pipeline - in the `HttpControllerHandler`, where the `HttpContent` is copied to the underlying `HttpResponse`'s `OutputStream` in an internal static method called `HttpControllerHandler.ConvertResponse`.  There aren't enough extensibility points on the class itself to be able to inject a task in the correct place to be able to log the *actual* response within the Web API pipeline.

So I'm faced with:

- Lifting `HttpControllerHandler` in it's entirety from the source
  code and importing it to my project (and all the internals it uses,
  which is not a nice thought), then customising it accordingly.
- Just force serialization early and catch the exception - I can log
  the exception but not the response.  There is one slight issue with
  this, though - writing the request ID to the response is very
  important, and when these formatting exceptions occur, the ID doesn't
  get written because `HttpControllerHandler` replaces the entire
  response with it's error response!
- Logging requests at the next level up from the Web API.  This
  isn't ideal because I only want ***Web API*** requests logged; and
  also the logging code has a dependency on the current request's
  HttpConfiguration object in order to grab a request-specific DI
  container for resolving database connections (its a multi-tenant web 
  service).

Ultimately the only real option is the last one - to do the work at the IIS or Asp.Net level.  So despite all those extensibility points in the Web API - you actually can't implement a 'complete' logging solution within it - that's really disappointing.