# How do I trap a SerializationException in Web API?

Tags: asp.net, serialization, exception, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.NET Web API web service which throws a SerializationException in certain circumstances. The problem is that I'm unable to trap and log this exception server-side -- the only place it shows up is in the body of the HTTP response to the client.

I registered an `ExceptionFilterAttribute` as described in [Exception Handling in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/exception-handling) and verified that it works properly when I throw an exception within my controller. Unfortunately the SerializationException is being thrown during the response (after the controller) and appears to be completely swallowed up by ASP.NET. I also tried hooking `Application_Error()` in Global.asax.cs but it didn't show up there either.

How can I catch SerializationException exceptions during the Web API response?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If, instead of returning an object, you use the `ApiController.CreateResponse()` method and return a `HttpResponseMessage` you can then do `response.Content.LoadIntoBufferAsync().Wait()` and that will force the serialization to happen whilst you are still in the action and therefore can catch the exception.

Comment: Perfect! Slight optimization, I made my action async and awaited LoadIntoBufferAsync so as not to block the thread.

Comment: @Mike Chances are that the LoadIntoBufferAsync is just moving bytes around in memory during the serialization process, so you are probably not doing any IO.  Therefore by making it async you are just switching from one thread pool thread to another thread pool thread, which will actually be detrimental to perf.  However, ff you know that your formatter is going to be blocked waiting for IO then async may help.

Comment: I'm definitely not an expert on Wait vs await, but my understanding is that Wait() blocks the current thread while the Task executes on another thread. await also blocks the current thread but it does so asynchronously, freeing up the thread to do other things and then resuming when the Task completes. Both cases involve a thread switch so I think performance will be similar, but the async approach allows for (slightly) more scalability. As I said, my knowledge on this is sketchy so we should probably ask Stephen Toub. :)

Comment: @Mike The particular exception I was trying to catch was serializing an EF query that couldn't be executed. Thus, in my case, the query had not yet been executed by the time the action is complete, and the serialization process will go execute the query. Doing this async will definitely help things in this case. =)

Answer (score 3):

You can catch all Web API exceptions by registering an implementation of `IExceptionHandler`.

See [Web API Global Error Handling](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/web-api-global-error-handling)

> ...there are a number of cases that exception filters can’t handle. For example:
>
> - Exceptions thrown from controller constructors.
> - Exceptions thrown from message handlers.
> - Exceptions thrown during routing.
> - Exceptions thrown during response content serialization .

One thing not mentioned in that article is that your `IExceptionHandler` must be registered, either by `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Add(...)` or via an IoC container configured to be used by `DependencyResolver`.

Answer (score 2):

BTW, Serialization of responses actually happens at the host layers(in HttpControllerHandler, when hosted in IIS and in HttpSelfhostServer, when hosted in SelfHost) which is way below the stack  and not immediately after the response is returned from an action.

WebAPI Stack Poster: http://www.asp.net/posters/web-api/ASP.NET-Web-API-Poster-grayscale.pdf

That said, I am not able to come up with a straight forward way to achieve this. This is cumbersome, but may be override the default Xml and Json formatter's WriteToStreamAsync methods and try-catch-log any exceptions?

Alternatively, you can enable Web API Tracing which would log the exceptions happening during serialization. But yeah, if you do not know for the requests which cause the serialization errors, then you might want to enable tracing all the time which i am not sure is something you might want to do.