# How to catch exception thrown during response model serialization

Tags: c#, exception, asp.net-web-api, serialization, datacontract

I have bad business logic inside model classes generating exceptions but which are not caught by exception handling. Is it possible to catch exceptions that occur during the serialization operation of my model by controller code exception handling?

code example:

**BrittleModel.cs**

```
[DataContract]
public class BrittleModel
{
    private string peanutBrittle = null;

    [DataMember]
    public string PeanutBrittle
    {
        get
        {
            // if not set generates exception during serialization
            return peanutBrittle.ToString();
        }
        set
        {
            peanutBrittle = value;
        }
    }
}
```

**api/brittle**

```
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        try
        {
            return Request
                .CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new Models.BrittleModel());
        }
        catch
        {
            return Request
                .CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Something went awry.");
        }
    }
```

**actual response - exception message isn't "Something went awry."**

```
<Error>
  <Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
  <ExceptionMessage>
    The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'.
  </ExceptionMessage>
  <ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException</ExceptionType>
  <StackTrace/>
  <InnerException>
    <Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
    <ExceptionMessage>
      Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    </ExceptionMessage>
    <ExceptionType>System.NullReferenceException</ExceptionType>
    <StackTrace>
      at test.Models.BrittleModel.get_PeanutBrittle() in Models\BrittleModel.cs:line 19 at
      WriteBrittleModelToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , ClassDataContract )
      at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj,
      XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context) at
      System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteDataContractValue(DataContract
      dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle) at
      System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithoutXsiType(DataContract
      dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle) at
      System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObjectContent(XmlWriterDelegator
      writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver) at
      System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObject(XmlWriterDelegator
      writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver) at
      System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObjectHandleExceptions(XmlWriterDelegator
      writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver) at
      System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.WriteObject(XmlWriter writer, Object graph)
      at System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream
      writeStream, HttpContent content) at
      System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, Object value,
      Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext, CancellationToken
      cancellationToken)
      --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
      at System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.<WriteBufferedResponseContentAsync>d__1b.MoveNext()
    </StackTrace>
  </InnerException>
</Error>
```

Comment: Have you read this article yet?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16552715/how-do-i-trap-a-serializationexception-in-web-api

Comment: thanks for sharing @virusstorm - I didn't see that article but the accepted answer will work for me